# What does "equatorial expansion" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What does "equatorial expansion" mean? Wells's short story Mr. Brisher's Treasure

> I surveyed the flushed countenance, **the equatorial expansion**, the masterly carelessness of his attire, and heaved a sigh to think that by reason of the unworthiness of women he must needs be the last of his race.

Comment: Presumably his waistline had expanded!

Comment: I've removed the second question about "must needs be". You can ask in another question if you're really interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### He had become fat.

His body is being likened to a sphere. Spheres have equators. It has grown larger round the middle. He tells the narrator early in the story that he had been 'slim', which is the opposite of 'fat'.

Equatorial

> 1. of, pertaining to, or near an equator, esp. the equator of the earth

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/equatorial)

Expansion

> Expansion is the process of becoming greater in size, number, or
> amount.

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/expansion)